# Alamofire combined upload progress for multiple files

Tags: swift, file-upload, progress-bar, alamofire, multipartform-data

I am using Swift 5 and Alamofire 5. I require to upload 2 files and 3 key-value pairs to a server. I also need to check the combined progress of the whole upload.

I tried this code:

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (MultipartFormData) in
                           MultipartFormData.append(videoData!, withName: "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "video/mp4")
                           MultipartFormData.append(logData!, withName: "log", fileName: "log.txt", mimeType: "text/plain")
                           MultipartFormData.append("\(value1)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "key1")
                           MultipartFormData.append("\(value2)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "key2")
                           MultipartFormData.append("\(value1)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "key3")
                       }, to: config.uploadURL)
                    .responseJSON { response in
                            debugPrint(response)
                        switch response.result {
                        case .success (let data):

                            let json = data as! NSDictionary
                            if let status = json["status"] as? String {
                                print(status)
                            }
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                            }
                        }
                        .uploadProgress { progress in
                                let frac = progress.fractionCompleted
                                let percent = Int(frac * 100)
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.progressLabel.text = "\(percent)% completed"
                                    self.progressView.setProgress(Float(frac), animated: true)
                                    if percent == 100 {
                                        print("Completed")
                                    }
                                }
                    }
```

Now I wanted to give an alert upon completion of all the uploads (together). Problem is that I am getting the print statement "Completed" 4 times, probably it is giving the progress for individual files, post data and final completion. If I put an alert, I get 4 alerts with a warning

> Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x106871000>  on <ViewController: 0x1060d3a00> which is already presenting <UIAlertController: 0x106860e00>

How do I only get the combined final upload progress?

Comment: I think `success` is getting called for every part of data pushed to server.

Comment: So, how can it be fixed? or is it like that only in Alamofire?

Comment: Why dont you rely on `responseJSON` to show your alert?

Comment: Thank you. That's a good alternative.